# Transfer from US 401k fund to Australian Superannuation fund

Tags: united-states, 401k, retirement, australia, superannuation

I worked in the USA for a number of years and have now relocated to Australia. I have balances in both US 401k fund (+ IRAs) and Australian superannuation fund.

It seems that the Australian superannuation fund has significant tax benefits over the 401k (investments and income are taxed at only 15%), and I'd be simplifying my life if I could consolidate the US based funds back to Australia. I would still hold the same type of assets, but the fund would be complying with Australian tax code rather the US.

So the question: best way to get this money out of 401k (and IRA) without penalty, or is this worth the pain and effort?

The only way that I can see to avoid the 10% penalty is to take the 'retire early' option of "[substantially equal periodic payments](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/retirement-plans-faqs-regarding-substantially-equal-periodic-payments)". You don't have to actually retire, but you do have to treat the fund as in retirement / payout mode and continue to recieve monthly or annual payments. This would work but would take a long long time to execute.

Paying the income tax + 10% seems painful, and probably doesn't make sense. But the headache of dealing with cross-border income as a retiree also seems ugly.

Thoughts?

Comment: I did this in reverse (moved from Australia back to the US) and had to take the tax hit when moving money from a super to an IRA. No international rollover that I know of.